# How to get the path of the file using the Select-String cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

I'm trying to replicate the following behavior in Powershell `(version 7.2.8)`:

```
# use `grep` to select file names from output of `git status` and delete them
git status | grep 'file-name-pattern' | xargs -I '{}' rm '{}'
```

In Powershell, I tried:

```
git status | Select-String 'file-name-pattern' -List | Remove-Item
```

and got the error:

```
Remove-Item: Cannot find path 'T:\my-app\.ci\InputStream' because it does not exist.
```

I have tried many variants of the above powershell command, but did not work. How can I replicate the behavior of the above linux command in powershell ?

Comment: Grep is built on LEX which is the linux version of Regex.  Error may be due to not having permission to delete file or to folder was already removed because it matched the pattern.  Powershell does not run As Admin unless you right click the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(git status | Select-String -Pattern 'regex-file-name-pattern' -Raw ).Trim() | Remove-Item
```

The issue is related to the object output of the `Select-String` command. By default `Select-String` creates `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` objects with a Path property containing the path of the input which in this case would be 'InputStream'. `Remove-Item` binds to this Path property and assumes it is a filename.  Since a full path is not provided it assumes the current path and tries to delete a file with this name and reports that it `Cannot find path 'T:\my-app\.ci\InputStream'`

To get the desired behavior of sending any matched filename lines directly as strings to `Remove-Item` we can include the `-Raw` switch to `Select-String` which will result in the matched lines being bound to the `-Path` parameter of `Remove-Item`.  Unfortunately due to the whitespace caused by the indention of the filename by `git status` `Remove-Item` will still fail to find the file.  To correct for this, we call the `Trim()` method on the outputted strings to remove the whitespace.